# Countable open intervals

Tags: general-topology

In lower limit topology  $\mathcal T_{ll}$  $[b_n \space a)$ is the basis element. Any open interval can be constructed from the basis if a lower $b_n$ is rational and approaches to some limit in a sequence. From here I understood that the rational numbers in an interval are countable. Are the called countable even they are infinite countable?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. If only finite sets were countable then we would not need the term “countable” to begin with, as “countable and finite” is equivalent to “finite”. But that's independent of topology, so you probably mean something different here.

Comment: The question falls on: are the number of the open sets  $(0, 1-\frac{1}{N})$ in the interval $(0,1)$ countable if $N\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: From your formulation I suspect there's some deeper misunderstanding involved (what does the $N\to\infty$ do in the question about the number of intervals?), but assuming that $N$ is supposed to be from the natural numbers (as the name suggests), then there is a very obvious bijection between the set of natural numbers and the set of intervals of that form.

Comment: $N$ is a natural number. The intervals $(0,1/2)$, $(0,2/3)$, $(0,3/4)$ $......$ $(0,1-1/N)$. As $N\rightarrow\infty$ is the number of open sets $(0,1-1/N)$ infinite countable?

Comment: Well, the answer is in my previous comment. Do you know what “infinite countable” means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Countable" means "can be put in a 1-1 correspondence with some initial set of natural numbers." (where "initial set" means that if $n$ is in the set, so is every $m < n$).

Initial sets of natural numbers come in two forms: $S_n = \{m \in \Bbb N\mid m < n\}$ and $\Bbb N$ itself. So countable sets can be either finite (in bijection to $S_n$ for some $n$) or infinite (in bijection to $\Bbb N$ itself).